# Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Invalid parameter thrown while create event in facebook using graph api

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am getting below error while trying to create event using graph api

Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Invalid parameter thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\base_facebook.php on line 1267

Can anybody help me on this.

Below is my code:-

```
<?php

include_once("facebook.php");

define("FACEBOOOK_API_KEY","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
define("FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY","XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

/*$name = $_POST['name'];
$token = $_POST['access_token'];
$startTime = $_POST['start_time'];
$endTime = $_POST['end_time'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$description = $_POST['description'];*/

$name = "My Amazing Event";
$token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx';
$startTime = '10/29/2011 12:00 PM';
$endTime = '10/29/2011 06:00 PM';
$location = 'Raipur';
$description = 'It will be freaking awesome';

$fileName = "tiger.jpg"; //profile picture of the event

$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'      => FACEBOOOK_API_KEY,
    'secret'     => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
    'cookie'     => false,
    'fileUpload' => true     // this is important !
));

$fb->setAccessToken($token);

$data = array("name"=>$name,
              "access_token"=>$token,
              "start_time"=>$startTime,
              "end_time"=>$endTime,
              "location"=>$location,
              "description"=>$description
              //basename($fileName) => '@'.$fileName
);

$post_data[basename($fileName)] = '@' . realpath($fileName);

    $result = $fb->api('/me/events', 'POST', $data);
    $facebookEventId = $result['id'];
    echo $facebookEventId;

?>
```

Prompt help will be much appreciated.Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following things:

1. Use the correct date/time formats as described on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events (Date-only (e.g., '2012-07-04') / Precise-time (e.g., '2012-07-04T19:00:00-0700'))
2. Put the access_token from $data to the calling url:

   `fb->api('/me/events?access_token=YOURTOKEN', 'POST', $data);`
3. Try to use your profileID instead of 'me'

   `fb->api('/YOURPROFILEID/events?access_token=YOURTOKEN', 'POST', $data);`

Comment: Thank you Petra. Your solution with date online worked for me (Date-only (e.g., '2012-07-04'))